# SQL Regex - Select everything after '/' and split into array

Tags: sql, regex, hsqldb

I have to write a HSQLDB query that splits this string on '/'

```
/2225/golf drive/#305/Huntsville/AL/1243
```

This is where I am at

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTRING_ARRAY(Terms, ''/[a-zA-Z0-9]*'') as ARR from Address
```

This is giving me

```
/2225, /golf, /, /Huntsville, /AL, /1243 - (Missing "#305" and "drive" in second split)
```

How can I modify the regex such that it includes everything after "/" and give me this result

```
/2225, /golf drive, /#305, /Huntsville, /AL, /1243
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case why can't you use `/[a-zA-Z0-9, #]*` regexp? It seems good for your goal.

I've checked, it works here for me: https://regex101.com/r/8bJQEk/1

PS This regexp `/\/([^\/]*)/g` can helps to split everything. Be careful with slashes). [Example](https://regex101.com/r/8bJQEk/4)

Comment: But this only works with #. I can get any special character in the string

Comment: @keanu If you want to split anything you can use it `/([^/]*)` regexp. It works [here](https://regex101.com/r/8bJQEk/3)

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks Denniselite